# Kohana 3.1 ORM relationships question

Tags: orm, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I'm using kohana3.

tables:
users id username friend_id

user_relationships id user_id friend_id

I'm trying to do the following:

Let's assume, I have id = 1 in user_table. Then I want to get array of friend_id for this user. Assume it would be (2,3). And then I want to get username for id = (2,3)

user model:

```
protected $_has_many = array(
    'userrelations' => array()
);
```

userrelationships model:

```
  protected $_belongs_to = array(
    'user' => array(),
);
```

controller:

```
$user = ORM::factory('user', 1);
$friends = $user->userrelations->find_all();
```

I only recive ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["user_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["friend_id"]=> string(1) "2"
What should I write to get what I want?

Comment: User has many friends, and user can be a friend for a lot of other users. Should it be has_many "through" (HABTM) relationship?

Comment: you're right, biakaveron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it should be like this:

in user model:

```
'friends' => array('model' => 'user', 'through' => 'user_relationships')
```

and i get all data needed like this:

```
 $friends = $user->friends->find_all();
```

where 'friends' is alias i'm using in user model

Answer (score 0):

Try using `as_array`

```
$user->userrelations->find_all()->as_array('col1', 'col2');
```